# slow(er) HDD performance

Tags: 12.10, hard-drive, performance

When watching a movie (simple avi) and my torrent client (transmission) runs simultaneously, the movie slows down. I think this is a HDD performance issue. It does not exist on windows 7/8 (same laptop).

My `hdpharm` output:

```
/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   7666 MB in  2.00 seconds = 3834.33 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 290 MB in  3.01 seconds =  96.28 MB/sec
```

What can be the problem?

It's a HP probook 4530s and wubi 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this explains it but the culprit may be the type of install, WUBI. From the [wiki on WUBI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29#Limitations):

**Limitation of WUBI**

... Performance related to hard-disk access is also slightly slower, more so if the disk image file is fragmented, on a Wubi install compared to a normal one. ...

Also see the [WUBI-FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).

This should not occur when Ubuntu is installed in its own ext4 partition (includes standard dual boot installs). Fragmentation is more of NTFS partition (used by Windows) problem than in ext4. The WUBI install uses a virtual disk (a large file) inside Windows NTFS partition. The virtualization also contributes to the slowness.

Comment: Does this also occur, if I am dual-booting? Not using WUBI.

Comment: Thanx, that will be a wubi limitation..